# AppArmor Not Recognizing Files & Directories That Exist (Syntax Error)

Tags: apparmor

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 server running AppArmor 2.13.3 and I have downloaded two additional apparmor profiles, from the [official apparmor repository][1]:

```
usr.sbin.apache2
php-fpm
```

Because I am running such an older version of apparmor (the only one available from my repository) I had to do three things in order to get the profiles / apparmor itself working:

**Things I did:**

1. I hashed out `#abi <abi/3.0>,`  in both profiles
2. In `/etc/apparmor.d/php-fpm`  I replaced the clauses using the run variables as follows:

   ```
   #we need to be able to create all sockets
   #@{run}/php{,-fpm}/php*-fpm.pid rw,
   #@{run}/php{,-fpm}/php*-fpm.sock rwlk,

   #DP Edits: New socket creation w/o run variable  
     /{var/,}run/php{,-fpm}/php*-fpm.pid rw,  
     /{var/,}run/php{,-fpm}/php*-fpm.sock rwlk,
   ```
3. I hashed out line 68 in `/etc/apparmor.d/php-fpm` and line 117 in `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.apache2`... This was necessary to resolve the following errors:

```
    root@test:/etc/apparmor.d# apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.apache2 
    ERROR: Syntax Error: Unknown line found in file /etc/apparmor.d/php-fpm line 68:
        include if exists <php-fpm.d>  include if exists <local/php-fpm> }
        
    ERROR: Syntax Error: Unknown line found in file /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.apache2 line 117:
        include if exists <local/usr.sbin.apache2> }
```

**Question/Problem:**
How do I adjust the syntax of line 68 in `/etc/apparmor.d/php-fpm`, so that it is compatible with my version of apparmor (2.13.3)?  Or is there a different problem causing the errors above that I don't understand?

Lines that I hashed out:
line 68 in `/etc/apparmor.d/php-fpm`

```
#load all files from this directory
  #store your configurations per pool in this dir
#include if exists <php-fpm.d>   <--hashed out by me

  #Site-specific additions and overrides. See local/README for details.
#include if exists <local/php-fpm>   <--hashed out by me
```

**Note:** the directory `php-fpm.d` and file `local/php-fpm` (empty) both exist.

**FYI**

line 117 in `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.apache2`

```
#Site-specific additions and overrides. See local/README for details.
#include if exists <local/usr.sbin.apache2>
```

Overall, I haven't noticed any problems being created by the profiles following my edits, but I run a Virtualmin control and will likely need to php-fpm child profiles.